# Where is my wordpress/wp-content/uploads file?

Tags: wordpress

I have found multiple questions and answers referring to the wordpress/wp-content/uploads file but I am new to creating websites and don't know where to find it. I searched my cpanel File Manager for it but it doesn't show me it. My host is Arvixe and I am using Wordpress.

Thank you

Comment: If you have ftp access to your domain then when you login click on the www folder (or public_html) and there should be a list of files and wp-content should be one of them

Answer (score 2):

The wordpress uploads file is located in `wordpress/wp-content/uploads`.

Note that this means that if you changed your install dir and named it `my_cool_site` it will actually be :

```
my_cool_site/wp-content/uploads
```

You can see it with `ftp`, `ssh`, or even with `cpanel file manager` like you stated trying to do in your question - **but**

That said, you must also know that on <strike>some</strike> most configurations , the

> **wp uploads dir will NOT exists until you actually make an UPLOAD**

The folder is created on-the-fly, with subfolders according to the settings ( year/month etc..)

Also note , that the upload folder LOCATION can be changed both by plugins / themes using the [wp_upload_dir()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_upload_dir) function, or by defining a constant like so :

```
define( 'UPLOADS', 'wp-content/'.'files' );
```

So if any of those occur on your installation - the upload dir will be MOVED to that specific location.